# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't open command prompt window after I run the code

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have one problem with Visual Studio 2012 which is when I run the code the command prompt window doesnt open. I think everything is ok with the code that when I debug and run it, appears a light blue bar below saying "Ready" after I debug and run the code but the command window doesnt open. What I should do for the command window to appear?

Comment: Are you developing a console application?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a problem where the command window stopped opening while I was debugging. (I had accidentally closed it out with the "X" previously.) Checking the MSDN help page gave me the following:

The Command window is used to execute commands or aliases directly in the Visual Studio integrated development environment (IDE). You can execute both menu commands and commands that do not appear on any menu. To display the Command window, choose Other Windows from the View menu, and select Command Window.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your project is not a Console Application. Double check!

Comment: I already double checked and it is indeed a Console Application so that's not the reason why the Command Prompt is not opening when I run the code. So what do you think could be the reason why it is not opening?